# Intuitive examples satisfying Restricted Strong Convexity

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I am reading "[A Tight Bound of Hard Thresholding](https://arxiv.org/abs/1605.01656#:%7E:text=This%20paper%20is%20concerned%20with,solution%20from%20a%20given%20signal.)" and on page 13 at definition 8 we have the following:

A differentiable function $f:\mathbb{R}^d\to \mathbb{R}$ is said to satisfy the property of restricted strong convexity (RSC) with parameter $\alpha_k >0 $, if for all vectors $x$ and $y$ in $\mathbb{R}^d$ with $||x-y||_0 \leq k$ it holds

$$f(y)\geq f(x)+\nabla f(x)\cdot(y-x)+\frac{\alpha_k}{2}||x-y||^2$$

where $||\cdot||_0$ is the number of nonzero elements.

What I am understanding is that the above condition says that along some directions our function is strongly convex. I am struggling to come up with good examples (or class of functions) that are easy to comprehend and can justify the intuition behind the definition.

**Question**: Can you please provide nonlinear examples that are intuitive and satisfy the above property?

Answer (score 3):

Let me give you another example that arises in statistical learning applications with sparsity constraints. There the function $f$ corresponds to the empirical risk function with squared loss. More precisely, suppose that we observe $n$ input-output pairs $(x_{i}, y_{i}) \in \mathbb{R}^{d} \times \mathbb{R}$ sampled i.i.d. from some distribution $P$ following the model:
\begin{align*}
  x_{i} &\sim P_{X}, \text{ where }P_{X}\text{ denotes the marginal distribution of }X,\\
  y_{i} &\sim \langle w^{\star}, x_{i} \rangle + \xi_{i}, \text{ where $w^{\star} \in \mathbb{R}^{d}$ is some $k$-sparse vector and $\xi_{i} \sim N(0, \sigma^{2})$.} 
\end{align*}
The aim is to construct an estimate $\widehat{w} = \widehat{w}((x_{1},y_{1}), \dots, (x_{n}, y_{n})) \in \mathbb{R}^{d}$ such that $\|\widehat{w} - w^{\star}\|_{2}^{2}$ is small. The setting of interest is when $k \ll n \ll d$.

Now let us define $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times d}$ and $y \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ by letting the $i$-th row of $X$ equal $x_{i}^{\mathsf{T}}$ and letting the $i$-th element of $y$ equal $y_{i}$. We can then define the empirical risk function by
$$
  f(w) = \frac{1}{2n}\|Xw - y\|_{2}^{2}.
$$
Observe that $f$ is not strongly convex, since its hessian is equal to $\frac{1}{n}X^{\mathsf{T}}X$, which is of rank at most $n \ll d$. At the same time, the condition $n \ll d$ implies that there exists an infinite number of $w \in \mathbb{R}^{d}$ attaining $f(w) = 0$ and thus minimizing $f$ is not enough to approximately recover the true parameter $w^{\star}$.

**Here is how the restricted strong convexity kicks in**. We can define our estimator (completely ignoring the computational issues) as any solution to the below equation
$$
  \widehat{w} \in \mathrm{argmin}_{w \in \mathbb{R}^{d}, \|w\|_{0} \leq k} f(w).
$$
Thus, the output vector is $k$-sparse (i.e., $\|\widehat{w}\|_{0} \leq k$) and in particular, $\|\widehat{w} - w^{\star}\|_{0} \leq 2k$. **The restricted strong convexity assumption ensures that $f$ contains enough curvature in the direction $w^{\star} - \widehat{w}$ such that small value of $f(w^{\star}) - f(\widehat{w})$ translates to a small $\ell_{2}$ norm $\|\widehat{w} - w^{\star}\|_{2}^{2}$.**

---

**When is restricted strong convexity satisfied naturally in the above example?** To finally answer the @Sepide's question, the strong convexity condition, in our example above, reads as:
\begin{align*}
  &f(w_{2})\geq f(w_{1})+\nabla f(w_{1})\cdot(w_{2}-w_{1})+\frac{\alpha_k}{2}||w_{1}-w_{2}||^2\\
  \iff&
  \frac{1}{2n}\|Xw_{2} - y\|_{2}^{2}
  \geq \frac{1}{2n}\|Xw_{1} - y\|_{2}^{2}
        + \langle\frac{1}{n}X^{\mathsf{T}}(Xw_{1} - y), w_{2} - w_{1}\rangle
        + \frac{\alpha_{k}}{2}\|w_{1} - w_{2}\|_{2}^{2} \\
  \iff&
  \frac{1}{2n}\|Xw_{2} - Xw_{1} + Xw_{1} - y\|_{2}^{2}
  \geq \frac{1}{2n}\|Xw_{1} - y\|_{2}^{2}
        + \langle\frac{1}{n}X^{\mathsf{T}}(Xw_{1} - y), w_{2} - w_{1}\rangle
        + \frac{\alpha_{k}}{2}\|w_{1} - w_{2}\|_{2}^{2} \\
  \iff&
  \frac{1}{2n}\|Xw_{2} - Xw_{1}\|_{2}^{2}
  \geq \frac{\alpha_{k}}{2}\|w_{1} - w_{2}\|_{2}^{2} \\
  \iff&
  \frac{1}{n}\|X(w_{1} - w_{2})\|_{2}^{2}
  \geq \alpha_{k} \|w_{1} - w_{2}\|_{2}^{2}.
\end{align*}
Thus, the restricted strong convexity condition, in our setting, reduces to a restricted eigenvalue condition on $\frac{1}{n}X^{\mathsf{T}}X$. Let $X_{S} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times |S|}$ denote a matrix constructed by taking columns of $X$ as specified by some support set $S \subseteq \{1, \dots, d\}$. Then another way to view the restricted eigenvalue condition is to say that
$$
  \text{for any }|S| \leq k\text{ we have } \frac{1}{n}X^{\mathsf{T}}_{S}X_{S} \succcurlyeq \alpha_{k}I.
$$
The above condition can be ensured, for example, by sampling the entries of $X$ by i.i.d. $N(0,1)$ distribution. Then, by results from random matrix theory you would have for any $S$, $\|\frac{1}{n}X^{\mathsf{T}}_{S}X_{S} - I\| \leq c\sqrt{\frac{\|S\|}{n}}$ with high probability, where $c$ is some absolute constant and $\|\cdot\|$ denotes the operator norm. By the union bound, taking $n \in \Theta (k \log(ed/k))$ samples would be enough to ensure restricted strong convexity with $\alpha_{k} \approx 1$ (in fact, this would ensure the stronger condition of restricted isometry property). The setting discussed in this post is natural, for instance, in compressed sensing applications, where you have full control over the marginal distribution $P_{X}$.

Comment: thank you for providing the example. As far as I understand, for the example you mentioned, the sample covariance matrix of the measurement matrix must be positive definite on the set of columns with cardinality of $k$. Am I right? If so, this example can be understood in a matrix regime better. What I am looking for is draw a conclusion about the nonlinear case? In this case, can you connect your explanation to what I am looking for?

Comment: Hi Sepide, you are absolutely right. Also note that in my example f is non-linear as f is a quadratic function - we were simply able to reduce it to a “linear” case.

Comment: To slightly expand on my comment, what was shown in the answer above is a condition on the hessian of $f$ (which is equal to $\frac{1}{n}X^{\mathsf{T}}X$): the restricted strong convexity condition for the quadratic function $f$ reduces to the if and only if condition on the hessian, requiring that it has sufficient curvature in "sparse" directions.

Answer (score 1):

This should be an example for $d=2$:
$$
f(x) = (|x_1|+|x_2|)^2.
$$
It is not strongly convex (constant on sets $|x_1|+|x_2|=c$). It should however satisfy the requirement for $k=1$: Take $x\in \mathbb R^2$, we need to check whether $t\mapsto f(x+ te_i)$ is strongly convex for unit vectors $e_1,e_2$. I.e., for $i=1$:
$$\begin{split}
f(x+te_1)&= (|x_1 + t|+|x_2|)^2 \\&= |x_1 + t|^2 + 2|(x_1+t)x_2|+|x_2|\\
&= t^2 + 2t |x_1| + x_1^2 + 2|(x_1+t)x_2|+|x_2|,
\end{split}
$$
which is the sum of a strongly convex ($t^2$) and convex functions, hence strongly convex.

Comment: thank you for providing an answer. Would it be possible to come up with an example that is not easily decouplable like the one we have hear? Also, if we put RSC functions in a class, what properties do they have? Can we say their hessian matrix is positive semi-definite along specific directions? If so, what does it mean? Furthermore, the curvature of the function you mentioned is always upward, is it the case for all RSC 2d functions? Moreover, If we were to compare 2d strongly convex functions and RSC ones, what could we say?